# How do I get the coordinates of the vectors that represent a contour shape which I have stores as a 2D numpy array of pixels?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1000x1000 2D numpy array that can be thought of as pixels of an image. The cells are 0 where there is no shape, and some value where the shape is, the value representing the intensity. It can be plotted like this:

```
plt.matshow(data, origin='lower')
```

[image: Matshow plot of the numpy array]

The data can be viewed as shape when considering only the data over a certain threshold, like so:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cluster_contour_threshold = 60
y,x = np.argwhere(data > cluster_contour_threshold).T

ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_xlim((0, 1000))
ax.set_ylim((0, 1000))
```

[image: Matplotlib scatterplot representing the numpy array]

What I want is the get a list of coordinates that represent the contour of this shape. Something like this:

```
[
  [x0,y0],
  [x1,y1],
  [x2,y2]
]
```

My best attempt so far have been using canny, but it's not quite right:

```
from skimage import feature
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

c = feature.canny(data)
y,x = np.argwhere(c).T


ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_xlim((0, 1000))
ax.set_ylim((0, 1000))
```

[image: Canny]

Comment: I think just `points = np.argwhere(c)`?

Comment: This would give you all the points that has data, not the contour.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with skimage.

```
from skimage import measure

contours = measure.find_contours(data, 0.8)

# Display the image and plot all contours found
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

for contour in contours:
    ax.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2)

ax.axis('image')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
```

[image: Plot with edge]